# Hadoop hdfs -copyFromLocal

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I have a small cluster running. On the master `jps`command is showing NameNode, ResourceManager and JobHistoryServer. For every node of the cluster `jps`command is showing the two processes DataNode and NodeManager.

To create a directory is possible, but `hdfs dfs -copyFromLocal /usr/local/input/file /data/input/` fails with the error message in the screenshot attached...

Why is it possible to create a directory but not to load a file?
Thanks for the hints

[image]

Comment: a remark: the message is: "Can't browse the DFS since there are no live nodes available to redirect to". For sure I've formatted the namenode before I've started the daemons.

Comment: Can you provide full log detail. From the screen shot, its unable to identify the error?

Comment: have u tried hdfs dfs -put /usr/local/input/file /data/input/

Comment: I found an error in the core-site.xml file. Now I have a strange problem. When I start the datanodes from the cluster (hadoop-daemons.sh start datanode), the datanodes are running. But when I check it a minute later using jps on the nodes, the datanode process is not running anymore???

Comment: I solved it by myself. I had to delete everything in the folder specified in hdfs-site.xml - "dfs.datanode.data.dir". (this post described the procedure: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16020334/hadoop-datanode-process-killed). The reason behind were  incompatible clusterIDs.